# HMSegmentedControl how to refresh its title

Tags: ios, uicontrol

I'm using HMSegmentedControl in my application. I created a HMSegmentedControl instance in view controller A, then jumped to view controller B to collect data, like this: 
 `[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];`

Then I went back to view controller A and changed the titles of HMSegmentedControl according to the values from view controller B. I used `setSectionTitles:` to do the job. The titles did not refresh until I clicked one of them, but I want it refresh immediately. How to do it?

I've tried `self.view setNeedsDisplay` but did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setNeedsDisplay` should do what you need. You just need to call it on the segmented control, not the view controller's view.

`[segmentedControl setNeedsDisplay];`